# PayPal Friends and Family via Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

I have my PayPal account set up to allow encrypted button payments only, and I am using Express Checkout via both a RSA encrypted button and the REST API.

But sometimes my friends will pay me back for something and we'd like to do that as Friends & Family to avoid fees. Express Checkout by default is goods & services, which makes sense.

Instead of having to log in and turn off the encrypted button setting and toggle back on every time, can I accept a friends & family payment through Express Checkout? If yes, how?

In the past Adaptive Payments could do personal payments, although AFAIK this is now depreciated and not recommended. So ideally whatever the new suggested way is.

Answer (score 0):

Friends and Family payments **cannot** be accepted through an Express Checkout (or more current [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/)) integration.

However it should be possible to accept both different types of payments in parallel through separate methods. You might find a [PayPal.me link](https://www.paypal.me/) convenient for Friends and Family, and/or the encrypted website payments option can simply be kept off since it is not needed.